# Why is my program not skipping a part of my code?

Tags: python

I am a beginner at programming and I need some help. I want my program to print different variables based on input. However, instead of printing one of the outcomes, both are being printed.
For example:

```
A6 = input(">>>")
A6_A = input(">>>")
A6_B = input(">>>")

if A6 == "1":
    A6 = "The cover is virtually undamaged. "

if A6 == "2":
    A6 = "The cover is scuffed. "

if A6 == "3":
    A6 = "The cover is faded. "

if A6_A == "1":
    A6_A = "The spine is virtually undamaged. "

if A6_A == "2":
    A6_A = "The spine is scuffed. "

if A6_A == "3":
    A6_A = "The spine is faded. "

if A6_B == "1":
    A6_B = "The dust cover is virtually undamaged. "

if A6_B == "2":
    A6_B = "The dust cover is scuffed. "

if A6_B == "3":
    A6_B = "The dust cover is faded. "

A61 = "No Print."
A62 = "No Print."

if A6 == "The cover is virtually undamaged. " and A6_A == "The spine is virtually undamaged. " and A6_B == "The dust cover is virtually undamaged. ":
    A61 = "The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged. "

if A6 == "The cover is scuffed. " and A6_A == "The spine is scuffed. " and A6_B == "The dust cover is scuffed. ":
    A62 = "The cover, spine, and dust cover is scuffed. "

## Output Code##
if A61 == "No Print." or A62 == "No Print.":
    print(A6 + A6_A + A6_B)
else:
    pass

if A61 == "The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged. ":
    print(A61)

if A62 == "The cover, spine, and dust cover is scuffed. ":
    print(A62)
```

When I input "1" "1" "1" I get the output of:
"The cover is virtually undamaged. The spine is virtually undamaged. The dust cover is virtually undamaged.
The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged."

instead of just "The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I would recommend more understandable variable names btw.
If's are in general not exclusive. You might want to try elif instead. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Comment: The value of `A62` is unchanged as `No Print.`, Hence the `or` block returns True. Try changing `if A61 == "No Print." or A62 == "No Print.":` to `if A61 == "No Print." and A62 == "No Print.":`

Comment: Your code would be much more manageable and readable if you prrform your comparisons with the input numbers only until the final output string is determined. For example,  if you wanted to change the wording slightly from "virtually undamaged" to "like new", you would have to change it in many places or your code would break. If you wait until the end, you could write it so that you only have to change it in over place.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

No situtation would change both `A61` and `A62` so the code `if A61 == "No Print." or A62 == "No Print.":` will always be true, because one at least will be True

Change to an `and`

```
if A61 == "No Print." and A62 == "No Print.":
```

---

#### Improve

Don't keep on settingstring,then compare them after (at least for when you need to modify one), try to get something more generic. Also use `elif` to avoid useless comparisons

Here's a code with many changes, but a lot more usable, like when the dynamic asking for each

```py
states = ["virtually_damaged", "scuffed", "faded"]
item_names = {"cover", "spin", "dust cover"}

# display the possible states and their choce indice
for i, state in enumerate(states, 1):
    print(i, "=>", state)

# ask user and save choices
items = {}
for item in item_names:
    choice = input(f"Choice for {item}: ")
    items[item] = states[int(choice) - 1]

# if all have same state : group the result
if len(set(items.values())) == 1:
    keys = list(items)
    names = ",".join(keys[:-1])
    result = f"The {names} and {keys[-1]} is {list(items.values())[0]}."
    print(result)
else:  # else print all 
    for item, state in items.items():
        print(f"The {item} is {state}. ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to change the `if` statement just below the `## Output code##` comment.

If you enter 1, 1, 1 to your program the `A62` variable contains "No error" this means that the `if` statement is true and all three strings are printed out.

#### Advice on the code

It is generally not a good idea to keep the *state* of your program in strings and direct the flow of the program using string comparisons. I recommend using numeric or boolean variables which you would compare in the code and direct the flow of the program using them. With that in mind your code could look like this.

```py
A6 = int(input(">>>"))
A6_A = int(input(">>>"))
A6_B = int(input(">>>"))

A61 = False
A62 = False

# driver code
if A6 == 1 and A6_A == 1 and A6_B == 1:
    A61 = True

if A6 == 2 and A6_A == 2 and A6_B == 2:
    A62 = True

## Output Code##
if A61 == False and A62 == False:
    print(A6 + A6_A + A6_B)

if A61 == True:
    print("The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged. ")

if A62 == True:
    print("The cover, spine, and dust cover is scuffed. ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a lot of if here, I suggest you to check this link, if you are a begginer may can help to improve your code :))
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

```
## Output Code##
if A61 == "No Print." or A62 == "No Print.":
     print(A6 + A6_A + A6_B)
else:
     pass
```

here the code doesn't work, beacouse the or operator return True (one of the two variables is always "No print"). You must change it with a and

```
## Output Code##
if A61 == "No Print." and A62 == "No Print.":
     print(A6 + A6_A + A6_B)
else:
     pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if A61 == "No Print." or A62 == "No Print.":
    print(A6 + A6_A + A6_B)
else:
    pass
```

Here You have used or operator, so when you input "1" "1" "1" it's going to execute the first if condition:

```
if A6 == "The cover is virtually undamaged. " and A6_A == "The spine is virtually undamaged. " and A6_B == "The dust cover is virtually undamaged. ":
    A61 = "The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged. "
```

Here the value of A61 is changing from "No Print." to "The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged. "
but it's not going to the second if condition, that's why the value of A62 is still now "No Print."

So if you want to print just "The cover, spine, and dust cover is virtually undamaged.", Use **and** operator instead of **or** operator. According to your requirement, your solution is :

```
## Output Code##
if A61 == "No Print." and A62 == "No Print.":
    print(A6 + A6_A + A6_B)
else:
    pass
```